# memory used in running a script in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I  am trying to run a script inside a docker container using this command

```
docker exec <container_id> nodejs /code/file.js
```

I need to get the memory used in this process

Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script in one terminal, and open another terminal and run

```
watch docker top <container_id> aux
```

This command will allow you to monitor the memory consumption of all processes running inside the container, including the script that you are running.